# Result of solving an unsolved problem?

Tags: problem-solving, conjectures, open-problem

I know that when some of the previously unsolved problems were solved they created new fields in mathematics. May someone explain to me what would be the result of a major problem like the Hodge Conjecture being solved vs a "smaller" problem like "Do quasiperfect numbers exist?" in today's society.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In mathematic, often solving a (hard) problem often create new tools and open new area of mathematics. Like Fourier created Fourier series to solve the heat equation. And today what's more important? Solving the heat equation or Fourier analysis? :p

Comment: If somebody proved $P=NP$ then that could have major consequences.

Comment: According to the suggestions for asking questions on this site, "We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed." I think this question is barely on the correct side of that line.

Comment: I was specifically asking if they would still have a major impact on today's society.

Comment: Russell Impagliazzo wrote a famous paper discussing five "possible computational worlds" and what they would be like, including what if P=NP, what if it is proved that there are no irreversible hash functions, and so forth. I recommend it.  The title is the not-very promising "A personal view of average-case complexity".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a theorem ($P=NP$) that would change the world if proven to be true:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem

As it says on the wiki page:

"Aside from being an important problem in computational theory, a proof either way would have profound implications for mathematics, cryptography, algorithm research, artificial intelligence, game theory, multimedia processing, philosophy, economics and many other fields."

I'm adding the following comment on May 4th:

Strictly speaking, to change the world we don't just need a proof that $P=NP$, we need a constructive proof that leads to efficient (i.e. practical) algorithms.  So, without a doubt, if somebody proved $P=NP$ *and* they prove there is an efficient polynomial time algorithm, then that person will have dramatically changed the world.

So regardless of all the qualifications posted in response to this thread, the answer to the original question remains affirmative.  There are open math problems whose solutions could change the world if they turn out to be true and somebody manages to prove them.

Comment: Ah so even today, problems of massive importance exist. Additionally, even solutions of smaller problems could bring about respectable impacts.

Comment: It would change the world only if a constructive proof would exist. If you prove that P=NP, but without a way to construct such algorithm, the world wouldn't change

Comment: The world would change because nobody would be able to trust RSA encryption anymore.  And the world runs on encryption these days.  Do you think the NSA would just proceed as normal the day after somebody proved $P=NP$?  I doubt it.

Comment: But do you trust the RSA encryption now? because if P=NP, it's unsafe **now**, a "theorical" proof won't change this fact.

Comment: Well I think most people believe $P$ does not equal $NP$.  So we proceed on faith.  If it were proven otherwise, that would have to change things.

Comment: Quoting Donald Knuth on the page you link: "I don't believe that the equality $P = NP$ will turn out to be helpful even if it is proved, because such a proof will almost surely be nonconstructive."  So, one of the most respected researchers in Theoretical Computer Science **does** believe the NSA would proceed (more or less) as normal the day after someone proved $P=NP$.

Comment: @Strants  The same page says "Aside from being an important problem in computational theory, a proof either way would have profound implications for mathematics, cryptography, algorithm research, artificial intelligence, game theory, multimedia processing, philosophy, economics and many other fields." So I guess one can pick and choose from that page whatever they want to believe.

Comment: *Even* if the proof is constructive, the best polynomial algorithm for RSA-breaking/SAT... can be $O(n^ {\text{some ridiculously high number}})$.

Comment: If someone proved $P \lneqq NP$, while it would be of great theoretical and technical importance, would the society in general change much?

Comment: why? no need, and not the place, for a in-depth analysis, but a sketch of why it is important would be interesting.

Comment: *puts tin foil hat on* maybe the NSA has already found a constructive proof that P = NP... (just kidding, or am I?)

Comment: Based on the comments I edited my answer to qualify that we need an efficient constructive proof to change the world.  So there is still an affirmative answer to the OP's question.

Answer (score 5):

Most of the time, the actual result isn't important as the theory. The reason why problems are unsolved is because either the math doesn't exist yet, or some connection between current fields has not been established yet.

Either way, creating new math and connecting existing math are the real reasons why solving open problems is important.

For example, if the word of god came down and told us that yes, indeed the Hodge conjecture was true/false, it would be nice but not nearly as groundbreaking as a proof for it.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @avid19 that generally it isn't the *results* of the breakthrough solutions that matter as much as how they open up new ways of thinking and new classes of problems.  Let's not forget that fields such as probability and combinatorics received great impetus by what today is a set of simple gambling problems addressed by Pascal and Fermat and others.  Our entire way of thinking expanded, and the range of problems we could address exploded... most important to problems not thought soluble.  I put the Four Color Theorem (which led to graph theory), Nash's Game Theory, chaos theory and many other domains in this class.

There are a whole host of problems for which we simply don't have mathematics yet to address.  Since I work in computation, my favorite example of this is Collatz's conjecture:  Determine whether the following algorithm for integers greater than 1 always terminates at 1:

- If $n$ is even, divide it my 2, otherwise compute $3n + 1$; iterate.

This has been verified for $1 < n < 2^{62}$ and my personal view is that indeed the function does always terminate at 1, but neither I nor anybody has a clue how to prove it.  Paul Erdös said of this problem:  "Mathematics may not be ready for such problems."

We don't yet have adequate mathematics to describe and predict a wide range of problems and are reduced to simulating the processes, such as the dynamics of clouds, specific neural activity in the brain, and so forth.  Perhaps new concepts that arise in solving the Collatz Conjecture will ultimately lead to such mathematical ideas.

Comment: How do you know that we don't have the mathematics yet to address? Maybe as avid19 said "some connection between current fields has not been established yet."

Comment: In my view, having two mathematical disciplines without the connection necessary to answer a question is tantamount to saying we do not have the mathematics yet.  The connection *is* part of mathematics, and not part of either component alone.  We had geometry and algebra (for instance), but *geometric algebra* is a full field of its own.  Many such hyphenated fields are of this nature.

Comment: David, ah I think I get you. So it may not be the case if the connection is not necessary to answer a question? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probabilistic_proofs_of_non-probabilistic_theorems

Comment: It's true that often the method is more important than the result.  Fermat's Last Theorem is a classic example.  Whole branches of math grew out of trying to solve it.  However, it's not always the case.  The RSA algorithm was a result that changed the world, many would call it revolutionary, but the proof was based on very simple math and provided no new methods.  It was just a cute trick nobody had noticed before - probably because until powerful computers it wasn't really that important.